# NSFetchedResultsController with a one-to-many relationship

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I'm looking to display data from a Core Data model in a `UITableViewController`.  Model has two entities, with a one-to-many relationship. I want the items from the many entity to be the rows, broken down into sections by the one. In the event no rows exist, I still want the section header to display.

I have a working `NSFetchedResultsController` table working for the many table only, but I need to expand it to the one-to-many relationship.  I'm having no luck making that work, and haven't found any examples on how to do this.

The table will display all items, not a subset.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Grouping into sections is easy with `sectionNameKeyPath:`. But I don't have a solution to display section headers for empty sections (which is also the contents your previous question).

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide any details about the model objects your using, my example will use the following model.

[image: Library <-->> Book]

The first thing I would suggest doing is look at the documentation for `NSFetchedResultsController`, specifically [`initWithFetchRequest:managedObjectContext:sectionNameKeyPath:cacheName:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFetchedResultsController/initWithFetchRequest:managedObjectContext:sectionNameKeyPath:cacheName:). it tells you everything you need to know about fetching you data into sections.

The important part is that the first sort descriptor must return a similar order as the `sectionNameKeyPath`.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Book"];

NSSortDescriptor *librarySort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *bookSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[librarySort, bookSort]];

NSFetchedResultsController *controller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                             managedObjectContext:context
                                                                               sectionNameKeyPath:@"library.name"
                                                                                        cacheName:nil];
```